# How do I handle end-user gas cost in a DApp

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, gas

So let's say I have a ERC20 token and a DApp that uses said tokens as the currency. Obviously when users interact with my DApp (by sending it some amount of tokens), there will be a gas price involved. I do not want users to have to worry about keeping their wallets stocked with ETH in order to pay the transaction fees involved with using my DApp. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I can see for that is to wait until the next release called **Metropolis**. EIP 86 (account security abstraction) will introduce a functionality to allow the contract to pay for gas instead of the sender.

> EIP 86 (account security abstraction) – move the logic for verifying
>   signatures and nonces into contracts, allowing developers to
>   experiment with new signature schemes, privacy-preserving technologies
>   and modifications to parts of the protocol without requiring further
>   hard forks or support at the protocol level. Also allows contracts to
>   pay for gas.